# How do I reproduce the following in latex

Tags: tikz-pgf, diagrams

[image]

Specifically, I am trying to create the effect of the card holder line where "Roger Wilcox" is shown above the dotted line. Noticing that the dotted line is not an \underline. It extends beyond the text. Any suggestion will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{arydshln}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{|ll|}
\hline
\multicolumn{2}{|c|}{Credit Card Charge Form}\\
Card holder: & \begin{tabular}[b]{p{6cm}}
Roger Wilcox \\
\hdashline[1pt/1pt]
\end{tabular}\\
Address: & \begin{tabular}[b]{p{6cm}}
13 High Street \\
\hdashline[1pt/1pt]
\end{tabular}\\
Card number: & \begin{tabular}[b]{p{6cm}}
~\\
\hdashline[1pt/1pt]
\end{tabular}\\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks so much for your reply. Would you mind expanding on the use of tilda on line th16? I tried to remove it and the result is ...weird. But I don't know what is the logic behind the use of tilda sign in this instance.

Comment: @jxhyc The `~` is just a space, it is just that there is something in the inner table so that it is not empty. You can also use `\mbox{}`, say, or a `\vphantom{a}`, say. None of these is a visible content.